# How do I handle shutdown executor in Guava callback?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, guava

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {};

ListenableFuture<?> future = executor.submit(runnable);

FutureCallback<?> callback = new FutureCallback() {

   @Override
   public void onSuccess(Object result) {}

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Throwable t) {}

};

Futures.addCallback(future, callback, executor);
```

This code submits a [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) for execution and then schedules a callback which is invoked after the runnable completes but on the same [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

I want to learn about the failure mode where the runnable is scheduled successfully but the executor is shutdown before the callback is invoked. How can I capture an exception representing this failure mode and handle any cleanup required?

My reading of the [Guava source](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.java#L1155) suggests that a [RejectedExecutionException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html) is swallowed and logged. I need to be able to capture this exception and close resources. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `ListenableFuture` and not `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: @Malt LF is what Guava uses ubiquitously.

Comment: @Malt I've decorated my `executor` with Guava's `MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(exeuctor)` which returns a `ListenableFuture`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I realize that. What I'm wondering is why use `ListenableFuture` at all at this point. `CompletableFuture` offers the same functionality without the use of an external library.

Comment: @nSheahan I understand, but that wasn't what I was asking. I asked **why** are you using `ListenableFuture` at all? Is there a specific reason? Since Java 8 we have the `CompletableFuture` type

Comment: @Malt I'm going to change my `executor` to be of type `ThreadPoolExecutor` and register a `RejectedExecutionHandler` with it.

Comment: @Malt, the `CompletableFuture` API is extremely large and complicated -- arguably much bigger than it needs to be -- and many frameworks (and developers!) prefer `ListenableFuture` ubiquitously.